# How to split the words in a sentence which has more than 40 letters in asp.net

Tags: c#

I have to split the word in a sentence which contains more than 40 letters....

```
   **For Example:**

    Hi Pranesh....I am new to C# asp.Net...**pranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitleppranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitlep**
```

I want to find the word which contains more than 40 letters and want to delete the letters from the word so that it contains only 40letters....

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I love extension methods!

I would do something like this:

```
 public static string Truncate(this string s, int maxLength) {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) || maxLength <= 0)
            return string.Empty;
        else if (s.Length > maxLength)
            return s.Substring(0, maxLength) + "&hellip;";
        else
            return s;
 }
```

EDIT: The question wasn't very clear. If you want to strip out all words less than 40 characters you could so something like:

```
 public string FindBigWords(string s) {
        Regex regEx = new Regex(@"\s+");
        string[] tokens = regEx.Split(s);
        string ret = "";
        foreach (var t in tokens) {
            if (t.Length > 40)
                ret += t;
        }
        return ret;
 }
```

Note I haven't tested the above and it's not very efficient. Probably want to change it to at least use a stringbuilder.

Comment: This will truncate a string of over `maxLength` characters, but what is being asked for is something that will truncate individual *words* in a string, where a word is over 40 characters long. I guess you'd want to wrap your method inside something that split up the string first.

Comment: What is FindBigWords supposed to do, when i give it that string it returns an empty string

Comment: Hrm... that's probably a problem with the Regex. As I said, untested. Try swapping it out for @"\s+"

Comment: In this code the string[] tokens contains only empty values (i.e) " "
its not returning the words

Comment: I just tested it and it works for me. Use the new Regex \s+ which matches white space

Answer (score 2):

first find all word which contains more than 40 letters

```
var a = content.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Length > 40);
```

then remove by forech loop

Comment: This doesn't count words separated by "." or any other symbol as a new word

Comment: +1. @Quinn351: god you're lazy! This is a good answer, just change the split to take more chars then: content.Split(new[] { '.', ' '});

Comment: @BritishDeveloper So add every possible symbol? There are a quite a few of them

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
string data = @"Hi Pranesh....I am new to C# asp.Net...**pranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitleppranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitlep**";
string[] split = Regex.Split(data, @"\s");
foreach(string word in split)
{
    if (word.Length > 40)
    {
        data = data.Replace(word, word.Substring(0, 40));
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't count words separated by "." or any other symbol as a new word

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
        static string FourtyLetterWords(string s)
        {
            var splitString = GetWords(s);
            return string.Join("", splitString.Select(u => u.Count() >= 40 ? u.Substring(0, 40) : u));
        }

        private static List<string> GetWords(string s)
        {
            var stringList = new List<string>();
            StringBuilder currentWord = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
            {
                if(char.IsLetter(s[i]))
                {
                    currentWord.Append(s[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    stringList.Add(currentWord.ToString());
                    currentWord.Clear();
                    stringList.Add(s[i].ToString());
                }
            }
            return stringList;
        }
```

Called using -

```
string test = FourtyLetterWords(@"Hi Pranesh....I am new to C# asp.Net...**pranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitleppranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitlep**");
```

Which returns -  "Hi Pranesh....I am new to C# asp.Net...**pranuvideotitlepranuvideotitlepranutitle**"

Answer (score 0):

```
public static string TruncateLongWords(this string sentence, int maximumWordLength)
{
    var longWords = sentence.Split(' ').Where(w => w.Length > maximumWordLength);

    foreach (var longWord in longWords)
    {
        sentence = sentence.Replace(longWord, longWord.Substring(maximumWordLength));
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

Comment: Strings are immutable, you need to do sentence=sentence.Replace or better still, use a StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

var a = content.Split(' ').Where(s => s.Length <= 40);

This will give the truncated content. You can use ToArray() on the var object to get a string array.